# JQuery - mouse leave event from multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to handle mouse enter/leave events on multiple HTML elements.
I have multiple HTML elements and I want to fire an event when mouse enters or leaves this particular group of elements. Note: I cannot "group" these elements within one parent div.

sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/727g4c7h/1/

```
<div id="d1" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red"></div>
<div id="d2" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue"></div>
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green"></div>
<div id="result">result</div>

$(function(){
    $('#d1, #d2').mouseenter(function(){
          $('#result').html('enter ' + Math.random()); //random to distinguish subsequent events
    });

     $('#d1, #d2').mouseleave(function(){
          $('#result').html('leave ' + + Math.random());
    });

});
```

event should be fired when mouse enters div #d1 or #d2 and leaves #d1 or #d2

Comment: And what does your code do wrong?

Comment: when you move from red to blue div, event is fired - this is not supposed to do

Comment: I haven't been around with jquery for a long time but try to adjust the position and the actual height of the div  for example                              if (!(position>$("#d1").height())), with this you would say if the position, the actual coordinates are not greater than the first div height then display the math.random otherwise if the position (coordinates are greater then, don't do anyhting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplify everything by utilizing classes instead of ids and use css properties instead of inline css for cleaner html.

Based on your comment above, Im guessing that you dont want to fire the `mouseleave` when moving from one div to the other but only when leaving all the divs. Added using `e.toElement || e.relatedTarget` to check and limit when the code is called.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.mouseWatch').mouseenter(function(){
          $('#result').html('enter ' + Math.random()); 
    });

     $('.mouseWatch').mouseleave(function(e){
          // get new element that is now hovered
          var element = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget;
          // only call our on leave code if the user's mouse left all mouseWatch divs
          if(!$(element).hasClass('mouseWatch')){
            $('#result2').html('leave ' + + Math.random());
          }
    });

});
```

```css
.red{
  background-color:red;
  }
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
  }
.green{ 
  background-color:green;
  }

.mouseWatch{
  width:100px; 
  height:50px; 
  float:left; /*added to better fit the space on SO*/
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mouseWatch red"></div>
<div class="mouseWatch blue"></div>
<div class="mouseWatch green"></div><br><br><br><br>
<div id="result">result</div><br>
<div id="result2">result</div> (added second result div to better show leave vs enter)
```